# Duplicate table in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

If we would like to replicate table in DAX, what syntax should we use?

```
DaxTable = CALCULATETABLE( 'MyTable' )
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it simpler by removing the `CALCULATETABLE` part. It doesn't need to be any more complicated than simply:

```
DaxTable = 'MyTable'
```